# How to get extra data in android and how to use it to mysql as param

Tags: php, android, mysql

i've tried to make a listview, i use extra data for the parameter

send :

```
Intent nextActivity = new Intent(DetailActivity.this,Kuisioner.class);
nextActivity.putExtra("idm", strNrp);
startActivity(nextActivity);
```

recieve :

```
Intent intent= getIntent();
final String MhsID = intent.getStringExtra("idm"); 
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sMhsID", MhsID));
```

is it necessary to show full code?
the logcat says that my second activity `has extras`. i think it means that my extra data successfully sent.
and `"sMhsID"`use this to my php file

```
<?php
    $objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    $objDB = mysql_select_db("mydb");

    $strMhsID = $_POST["sMhsID"];
    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM student_mk WHERE 1 AND id_mhw = '".$strMhsID."' ";
    $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
    $intNumField = mysql_num_fields($objQuery);
    $resultArray = array();
    while($obResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))
    {
        $arrCol = array();
        for($i=0;$i<$intNumField;$i++)
        {
            $arrCol[mysql_field_name($objQuery,$i)] = $obResult[$i];
        }
        array_push($resultArray,$arrCol);
    }

    mysql_close($objConnect);

    echo json_encode($resultArray);
?>
```

but my listview shows nothing and the logcat shows no error, is there anything wrong with those scripts? please help me, i really need it. if its necessary to show the full code then tell me.

Comment: This code is vulnerable to injection. What is the version of PHP that u are using?

Comment: Did you check the output of the PHP script?

Comment: Try to log and print things in both places Android logcat and PHP script as well. May be you are not notifying your listView. Check that

Comment: @HristoValkanov PHP/5.2.9

Comment: @KNeerajLal how to check it? :(

Comment: @ashutiwari4 how to do that? :((

Comment: Change youR $_POST TO $_REQUEST and call youR page in the browser like http://www.yousite.com/yourscript.php?sMhsID=valid_id and check its output.

Comment: @KNeerajLal the output is right, it shows the selected data. but shows nothing on my listview. when i change `"SELECT * FROM student_mk WHERE 1 AND id_mhw = '".$strMhsID."' ";` to `"SELECT * FROM student_mk WHERE 1 AND id_mhw = valid_id ";' my listview shows the right data. can you explain whats wrong?

Comment: is it matter if i get the same extra data twice?

Comment: Is id_mhw an integer or varchar?

Comment: @KNeerajLal integer or numbers

Comment: change you query to "SELECT * FROM student_mk WHERE id_mhw = $strMhsID"

Comment: @KNeerajLal my other activity works fine using `$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM student_mk WHERE 1 AND id_mhw = '".$strMhsID."' ";` still shows nothing in my listview after i changed the query like u said

Comment: What details are shown in the list view? Is it regarding a single item or all items in the table?

Comment: @KNeerajLal all items with current parameter. i think the problem is extra data can't be reused to another activity. how to reuse extra data for more than one activity?

Comment: Did u try to Log the value in Logcat?

Comment: @all : finally i gave up and try to remake it with another method. thanks for answering, learned more stuff from it :D